# Unable to convert firebase json with inner node to java class

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my dataSnapshot as json

```
"-KcktjZcxPUqfxSjmOQR": {
    "EmailId": "IronMan@Avengers.com",
    "Locations": {
        "-KckvuDrlXOHiI0myZ0o": {
        "Latitude": "17",
        "Longitude": "78",
        "RecordedDateTime": "1254"
     },
        "-Kcl0vNZy4zcCaZTmg8a": {
        "Latitude": "17",
        "Longitude": "78",
        "RecordedDateTime": "1254"
     },
    "MobileNumber": "999999999999",
    "UserName": "Iron Man"
   }
}
```

My java classes

User class

```
public class User {
    private String EmailId;
    private String MobileNumber;
    private String UserName;
    private Map<String,Object> Locations;

   //constructor, getters and setters below
}
```

Location class

```
public class Location{
    private String EmailId;
    private String MobileNumber;
    private String UserName;
    private Map<String,Object> Locations;

   //constructor, getters and setters below
}
```

But still when I convert the json into a java object, the Locations Map is null.

```
User tempUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

Comment: Please share some more information about, say, how you queried for that snapshot, or perhaps what the snapshot toString() looks like?  As it stands now, we're only left to assume that your query is correct and it surfaces actual data.  Note that getValue can, in fact, return null if there is not data at the location of your query.